# Hex => char = 0 ? (Си)

Tags: c, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток!

Мне требуется перевести входящую информацию типа hex в char. К сожалению, ниже приведённый код любую входящую информацию превращает в (null).

Мог бы кто-нибудь указать на ошибку?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char in[255];
    fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);
    int i = 0;
    char myChar;

      while(in[i])
        {
            in[i++] = myChar;
            if(i == 2)
            {
                i = 0;
                myChar = strtol(in, NULL, 16);
                printf("%c", myChar);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: А это точно весь код? Есть у меня подозрение что он и собираться-то не должен...

Comment: Забыл массив вставить :) Поправил

Comment: Использование неинициализированной переменной myChar как минимум... Ну и вообще в отладчике посмотрите что у вас там происходит.

Comment: @Arden  Покажите на примере, как выглядит входящая строка, что и вы должны получить в результате. Что касается вашего кода, то он бессмысленен.

Comment: Вход: 48656c6c6fa
Выход: Hello

А что конкретно там бессмысленно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мои пять копеек.:)

Правда у меня решение получилось не такое уж и компактное, зато оно проверяет, если в строке встретился символ, который не представляет собой шестнадцатиричную цифру, то он пропускается.

Оно преобразует исходную строку шестнадцатиричных цифр в строку символов, имеющих соответствующие коды, составленные из смежных шестнадцатипичных цифр. То есть делает преобразование "на месте".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   266

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[N];

    fgets( s, N, stdin );

    s[strcspn( s, "\n")] = '\0';

    char *p   = s;
    int valid = 0;

    for ( char *q = s; *q; ++q )
    {
        if ( isxdigit( ( unsigned char )*q ) )
        {
            char c = toupper( ( unsigned char )*q );
            c = isalpha( ( unsigned char )c ) ? c - 'A' + 10 : c - '0';

            if ( valid ^=  1 ) 
            {
                *p = c;
            }               
            else
            {
                *p <<= 4;
                *p++ |= c;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 0;
        }
    }

    *p = '\0';

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести строку

```
48656c6c6f20576f726c6421
```

то вывод на консоль будет

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: То что нужно. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Arden Не за что. У вас сегодня богатый выбор из представленных решений.:)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, просто и неэффективно :) - например, так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char * in = "48656c6c6f0a";
    char hex[3];
    int x;
    for(char * c = in; *c; ++c)
    {
        hex[0] = *c++;
        hex[1] = *c;
        hex[2] = 0;
        sscanf(hex,"%x",&x);
        printf("%c",x);
    }
}
```

Берем по два символа из входящей строки, сканируем как шестнадцатеричное значение, выводим как `char`...

Или даже короче:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char * in = "48656c6c6f0a";
    int x;
    for(; *in; in+=2)
    {
        sscanf(in,"%2x",&x);
        printf("%c",x);
    }
}
```

Без `sscanf`:

```
int toInt(char c)
{
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) return c-'0';
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f')) return c-'a'+10;
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F')) return c-'A'+10;
    printf("Wrong symbol!\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char * in = "48656c6c6f0a";
    int x;
    for(; *in; in+=2)
    {
        x = toInt(*in)*16+toInt(*(in+1));
        printf("%c",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению мне нельзя использовать scanf.

Comment: Сильно эффективнее что-то не придумывается. Только свою функцию писать для каста чара в инт.

Comment: @Arden Ну, нате вам вариант без него... (См. дополненный ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a = 0x48;
int b = 0x45;
int c = 0x4C;
int d = 0x4C;
int f = 0x4F;

char h;
char e;
char l_zero;
char l_uno;
char o;

h = a; e = b; l_zero = c; l_uno = d; o = f;

cout << h << e << l_zero << l_uno << o << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Увы, в C `cout` не предусмотрен...

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/PUB59P

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *in= "4A75737420612074657374";
    unsigned q;
    int ch;

    for (q=0; in[q]; q+=2)
    {
        sscanf(in+q, "%2X", &ch);
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без scanf: http://ideone.com/oKqhFg

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digit(char ch)
{
    return ch - (ch<='9' ? '0': ch<='Z' ? 'A'-10 : 'a'-10);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *in= "4A75737420612074657374";
    unsigned q;

    for (q=0; in[q]; q+=2)
        printf("%c", (digit(in[q])<<4) | digit(in[q+1]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Требуется вывод с клавиатуры. При использовании fgets выводит 0

Comment: @Arden, ну так используй `gets`.

Comment: И 0 оно всё равно не выводит.